# Grabbing User Input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Let's say I have the simple form above. How would I grab what the user inputted in the First Name field in JS. I tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].onclick = function() {
    inputted = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].innerHTML;
}
```

But that doesn't work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `value` for text inputs:

```
 inputted = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

Also make sure to add `var` keyword to your variables so that you don't create a global variable:

```
var inputted = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

You should also not put closing `</input>` tag since it is **self-closing** tag:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
```

---

By the way you can also get elements value using below syntax:

```
formName.elementName.value;
```

Or

```
document.forms['formName'].elementName.value;
```

In your case it would be:

```
var inputted = formName.firstname.value;
```

Or

```
var inputted = document.forms['formName'].firstname.value;
```

Replace `formName` with whatever name is of your `<form>` element.

---

Lastly you can also get element's `value` if you apply `id` to it:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
```

and then use `getElementById`:

```
var inputted = document.getElementById('firstname');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
      i=inputs.length;
 //
    while(i--){
               inputs[i].onclick=myClickEventHandler;
     };
//
 function myClickEventHandler(evt){
    var myVal;
     switch (this.name) {

        case 'firstname':

             myVal = this.value;
            break;
    };
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a form, you could try something like this instead :

```
var input = document.forms["formName"]["fieldName"].value;
```

Else, make use of the `.value` attribute :

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```